# Custom Position Sizes with Pine and WunderTrading

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I've a finished strategy in Pine that backtests well, and I'd like to automate it by sending alerts to Wundertrading. The strategy calculates a custom position-size for each order, based on the current equity and a percentage per-order to risk. The position-size is passed to the 'qty' parameter of the 'strategy.entry' function.

My issue is that WunderTrading interprets all 'qty' values as cash, rather than contracts, and that (as far as I know) the 'strategy.entry' function does the opposite.

I can calculate the cash-value of orders in TV, but as soon as I enter that in to the 'strategy.entry' function, the strategy's calculations are thrown off, affecting the instructions it sends on to Wundertrading.

Consider a long trade calculated at a quantity of 1 ETH by my strategy. As it is, Wundertrading would read this as an instruction to purchase $1 of Ethereum. So I calculate the cash value - say, $1600 - and enter that in to the 'qty' parameter of the relevant functions. Tradingview now reads the order as purchasing 1600 ETH!

That would be fine if the same orders were executed in both cases. But, clearly, whether Tradingview records a successful long for 1 ETH or for 1600 ETH has a drastic effect on the next order it sends out.

It seems there's no way of getting WunderTrading to accept custom orders in a contract format. Is there a way to get Tradingview to accept a custom cash-value amount for each order?

**Update 1**

Mr Statler below has suggested altering `default_qty_type` to `strategy.cash`, but doing so doesn't solve the problem. Here's an example of the strategy running with positions in contract format:

[image]

And here's an example of the same strategy with the `strategy.cash` alteration, plus a few minor necessities:

[image]

I may need to post the scripts - I suspect there's something fundamentally wrong with the way I've handled position size.

**Update 2**

Here's an example of some of the relevant code for the script that calculates position size in contracts:

```
long_position_opened = strategy.position_size == 0 and long_condition
short_position_opened = strategy.position_size == 0 and short_condition
entry_price = ta.valuewhen(long_condition or short_condition, close, 0)
long_diff = (ta.valuewhen(long_position_opened, math.abs(stopvalue - entry_price), 0))
short_diff = (ta.valuewhen(short_position_opened, math.abs(entry_price - short_stopvalue),0))
balance = (strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit)
balance_limited = (balance > 0 ? balance : 0)
equityrisked = (i_risk/100) * balance_limited
pos_size = (equityrisked / long_diff)
short_pos_size = (equityrisked / short_diff)
```

And the code for position size in cash is the same, except for (1)  `default_qty_type` and (2) the following:

```
pos_size = (equityrisked / long_diff) * entry_price
short_pos_size = (equityrisked / short_diff) * entry_price
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `default_qty_type` argument in your `strategy()`:

> default_qty_type (const string) Specifies the units used for `default_qty_value`. Possible values are: strategy.fixed for contracts/shares/lots, strategy.cash for currency amounts, or strategy.percent_of_equity for a percentage of available equity. This setting can also be changed in the strategy's "Settings/Properties" tab. Optional. The default is strategy.fixed.

Comment: Thanks Mr Statler - I've already tried altering the `default_qty_value` parameter as you suggested, but if I do, (1) the backtesting results come out completely differently, and (2) the strategy no longer enters short positions at all. I'll edit my question and try to show what happens.

Comment: Firstly, I've suggested to alter the `default_qty_type` argument not `default_qty_value` argument (you can alter both of them if that's what you're looking for). Second - I've might misunderstood your question. You're looking for the backtesting to be calculated in contracts and just the alerts to be in cash? Or you want them both be in cash? And if you want the order to be calculated in cash, is it the initial cash? fixed sum of cash? total current cash (initial cash+ profit - loss)?

Comment: Sorry, yes, that was a typo, above. As far as the question is concerned, I would be happy for either the backtesting to be calculated in contracts and the alerts in cash, or for them both to be in cash. And I understand that the backtesting results ought to be the same for both alternatives (so long as I have converted the order quantities correctly.) But the backtesting varies. Let's say I want to calculate the orders in cash, I would like my strategy to maintain 1% risk of the current balance, as you have it (initial cash, plus net profit).

Comment: At the moment, the script does what's necessary to maintain that 1%, but it calculates the order sizes in contracts. When I alter the formula to calculate the cash amount (by multiplying contracts by entry price and changing default_qty_type to cash), I encounter the problem I posted above.

Comment: You can't use this argument to get 1% of the current balance. You can use it to get 1% of current equity, which includes open trades profit/loss. If you want 1% of current balance, you'll have to calculate it yourself

Comment: Thanks again Mr Statler - I know of the difference between current equity and the current balance. I believe I've accounted for that in the script.

Comment: Check the second update above - what do you thinK?